# Convert user input letters char to int?

Tags: java

This is a battleship game between user/comp & inputs are received from user as letter+number (ex: A1, B4, etc.). The array is an 8x8 grid so it has to be between A-H & 1-8.

I have it working for when the user enters a capital letter, but small letter produces an error (obviously because my code is kind of a quick fix by subtracting 65 from the input...

How can I make it so the user can input a1 or A1 and both will be the same number and same location on the grid?

Comment: FYI—the magic number 65 is 'A', which is a UTF-16 code unit. That makes sense because the `charAt` used in the answers returns a UTF-16 code unit. It would be easier to read if  - 'A' was used: It means "distance from [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already able to manipulate upper case letters, to make lower case letters work as well, you can simply convert the character to upper case first, like so:

`int precolumn = Character.toUpperCase(answer.charAt(0)) - 65;`

This will ensure that all the prepended alphabets are uppercase, so that your quick fix will work.

However, since you are aware that this is a lazy conversion, you may want to consider adding in additional steps like first converting the character to its ascii value through type casting: `int ascii = (int) character;` before doing the subtraction with an integer value...

Comment: Will this code ignore/not do anything if the user is entering already an uppercase char?

Comment: haha you can actually try things out for yourself, but anyway, `Character.toUpperCase('Q') = 'Q'` so...